# invoke exitprocess result in Need a prototype for procedure error under linux

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I have this simple code :

```
.data
sum DWORD 0
.code
main: 
  mov eax,5
  add eax,6
  INVOKE ExitProcess,0
end main
```

I'm using jwasm under arch linux 64 bit, When I run jwasm -elf64 I get this error : `Error A2159: INVOKE requires prototype for procedure` on the line :
`INVOKE ExitProcess,0`.

From searching I think I need some include file, I discovered what include is needed in MASM but I'm using jwasm and not in windows, So from where do I get ExitProcess ?

PS:
I'm still learning x86 assembly and this is my first code in it, I'm only familiar with mips assembly.

Comment: `ExitProcess` is a winapi function, on linux you can use the standard C `exit` function or just `ret` from `main`.

Comment: @Jester `ret` worked but `INVOKE exit,0` didn't, is this the right way to invoke `exit` ?

Comment: `INVOKE` is a macro, I assume if it exists it should work. But the real way to invoke `exit` is `mov edi, 0; call exit`.